# Finding value of f(n) using given binomial series

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

[image]

I thought of multiplying the expression for (1+k)^n by itself twice and trying with coefficients but none of them can construct this series. Any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: You should use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of posting a picture of the equation.

Comment: And also, please show your own working and the exact point during solving where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write out $(1+x)^6$ using the binomial theorem and differentiate it. What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

So we take the expression as given and differentiate it twice and finally multiply with the initial series to get the reqd. answer.